# repaint function not working ..

Tags: java, repaint

i have a problem with the repaint function

when i compile, the error is

```
pc3@pc3-desktop:~/Desktop$ javac LoadImageApp.java 
LoadImageApp.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method repaint(int,int,int,int,int)
location: class java.awt.Graphics
g.repaint(1000,0,0,1440,900)
 ^
1 error
```

and this is my code -->

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class LoadImageApp extends Component {

BufferedImage img;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
super.update(g);
g.repaint(1000,0,0,1440,900);
      }

public LoadImageApp() {
try{
   img = ImageIO.read(new File("screenshot.jpg"));
  }catch(IOException e){}
 }

 public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    if (img == null) {
            return new Dimension(100,100);
    } else {
       return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
   }
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image ");

    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
         });

 f.add(new LoadImageApp());
     f.pack();
     f.setVisible(true);



   }
}
```

can anyone tell me what is the problem ? i intend to do a program that is display the image and keep refreshing every 0.1 seconds . the image will be receive from other machine and every 0.1 seconds and  the image will be keep override the old image ..

thanks in advance for those who reply .. THANK YOU !!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend reading the [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) tutorials and understand the methods defined in the Graphics class as well as the `Component` class.  More specifically, what do you expect the statement:

```
g.repaint(1000, 0, 1440, 900)
```

to do?  If it's repaint one of your components based on some interval, you can do this using a [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).  Also from reading the tutorials you'll see why you have a compilation error.  The `repaint` method is not defined on `Graphics`.

As a side note, don't name your method paint - it's confusing since there is a `paint` method already defined in `Component`

Comment: the g.repaint(...) i reference from the link below  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

and i am very confused about the graphice and component coz i am new to java. .. erm .. if i want to load image , display and refresh, which 1 is more suitable for me to use it ? thenks in advance for reply ..

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know where you found that `repaint` method signature for `Graphics` since it does not exist.

You should instead call repaint on the component which is the owner of that specified `Graphics`, which is the `LoadImageApp` itself.

But first of all you absolutely need to study a little bit better how drawing works with AWT and Swing, take a look [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/).

In Addition you should use something that schedules your update phase, otherwise your code, as it is, doesn't make any sense. There is nothing that is periodically loading the imagine neither anything that is repainting the frame. I'd suggest a `TimerTask` like Amir told you.

Comment: the g.repaint(...) i reference from the link below  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

and i am very confused about the graphice and component coz i am new to java. .. erm .. if i want to load image , display and refresh, which 1 is more suitable for me to use it ? thenks in advance for reply ..

Comment: Notice that the method is defined on the Component class.  Read the tutorial I referenced.